# Breaking an un-directed connected graph into two components

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-algorithm

Is there any algorithm to break a **Connected Undirected Graph** into **exactly 2** connected components by **deleting *Minimum* number of vertices**.

**Example 1:** edge list [1-2, 2-3, 3-4], here we can *delete vertex number 2 or vertex number 3* to decompose the graph into two connected component.

**Example 2:** edge list [1-2, 2-5, 2-3, 3-4], here we cannot *delete vertex number 2* as *it decomposes the graph into 3 connected components* (which we don't want) but we can *delete vertex number 3* to decompose the graph into two connected components.

Comment: Please clarify the following, Should the algorithm be able to recognize instances where a decomposition into exacly two connected components is impossible, like in the following edge list? `[1-4, 2-4, 3-4]`

Comment: Yes, or maybe just report how many connected components it is decomposing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for [minimal vertex separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator) algorithm.